# Beautiful soup loop keeps failing

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

EDIT: I have changed the code as required, however throwing out a different error message.

I am a relative noob to Beautiful soup and coding to a certain degree, just looking for a quick pointer to see where I am going wrong. Basically I am tyring to scrape my website and return a list of prices and product names.

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime

quote_page = 'http://www.golfspikesdirect.com/all-golf-spikes/'

page = urllib2.urlopen(quote_page)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')

product_name = {'class': 'card-title '}
product_price = {'class': 'price--withoutTax '}

divs = soup.findAll(class_ = "card-title") + soup.findAll(class_ = "price--withoutTax")

for product in divs:
    name = product.find(attrs=product_name).text.strip()
    price = product.find(attrs=product_price).text.strip()
    print "%s - (%s)" % (name, price)
```

Comment: `Beautiful soup loop keeps failing`. Why? In what way is it failing? What is your expected output? Where is your url?

Comment: Please provide us with the error code, it's unclear what is failng.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jonathonlenoury/Desktop/Scraper_v.01", line 23, in <module>
    name = product_name.text.strip()
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'text'
[Finished in 1.363s]

Comment: put Traceback in question. It will be more readable.

Comment: `product_name` is your dictionary which doesn't have method `text`. it seems you need `product.find(product_name).text.strip()`. The same problem is with `product_price`

Comment: new error as follows
   
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jonathonlenoury/Desktop/Scraper_v.01", line 19, in <module>
    name = product.find(attrs=product_name).text.strip()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
[Finished in 1.277s]

Answer (score 1):

`product_name` and `product_price` are normal dictionaries and dictionares don't have method `text` but you treats them as `BeautifulSoup` method `find`.

You need

```
name = product.find(attrs=product_name).text.strip()

price = product.find(attrs=product_price).text.strip()
```

Comment: import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from datetime import datetime

quote_page = 'http://www.golfspikesdirect.com/all-golf-spikes/'

page = urllib2.urlopen(quote_page)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')

product_name = {'class': 'card-title '}
product_price = {'class': 'price--withoutTax '}

    divs = soup.findAll(class_ = "card-title") + soup.findAll(class_ = "price--withoutTax")

for product in divs:
    name = product.find(attrs=product_name).text.strip()
    price = product.find(attrs=product_price).text.strip()
    print "%s - (%s)" % (name, price)

Comment: maybe in question add line `EDIT:` and append your code with new error message and description. don't change old code.